# How to remove the UILocalNotification repeat interval?

Tags: objective-c, uilocalnotification

i added a UILocalNotification with repeat interval of a minute.
how to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];`

**just copy it** under the method `didLaunchWithOptions` or `viewDidLoad` or even on your next `UILocalNotification` code.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)scheduleNotificationOn:(NSDate*) fireDate
                          text:(NSString*) alertText
                        action:(NSString*) alertAction
                         sound:(NSString*) soundfileName
                   launchImage:(NSString*) launchImage
                       andInfo:(NSDictionary*) userInfo
{
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = fireDate;
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.alertBody = alertText;
    localNotification.alertAction = alertAction;
    localNotification.soundName = soundfileName != nil ? soundfileName : UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotification.alertLaunchImage = launchImage;
    localNotification.userInfo = userInfo;

    for (UILocalNotification *notification in [self allLocalNotifications]) {
        if ([notification.fireDate timeIntervalSinceDate:localNotification.fireDate] == 0 &&
            [notification.alertBody isEqualToString:localNotification.alertBody]
            ) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    [localNotification release];
    return YES;
}
- (NSArray *)allLocalNotifications
{
    return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
}
- (void)cancelLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
}

- (void)cancelAllLocalNotifications
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
}
```

you should make a unique identifier to remove notification, such as alertBody..
then

```
- (void)cancelLocalNotificationByAlertBody:(NSString *)alertBody
{
    for (UILocalNotification *notification in [self allLocalNotifications]) {
        if ([notification.alertBody isEqual:alertBodyString] ) {
            [self cancelLocalNotification:notification];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit(rawValue: 0)
```

This code is in Swift. Try with the same thing in objective-c.